# My Canada visitor visa was refused; how can I address the issues?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals

[image]

I have questions about my visitor visa to Canada being refused due to 3 reasons:

- Based on family ties
- Based on purpose of visit
- Based on length of stay (I said I want to stay 1 month)

Anyway, all of my family have protected refugee status in Canada. I was back in my home country when they claimed refugee status. I have had a Canadian visa previously and I traveled back and forth to Canada. Unlike my family, when my husband and I applied for a visit visa, we included a no-objection letter from our jobs and an invitation letter from my father. He is a cancer patient which makes it more necessary for me to go and visit him.

However, We got refused. What can I do next? How can I overcome the reasons for the rejection? In my country, we don't have a visa application centre; can the location of the VAC affect the decision?

Comment: Did your husband also apply for a temporary visitor visa to make the visit with you? Was he approved or refused? Or does he already have a visa to Canada?

Comment: Yes i apply for him with me and we both get refused based on the letter I attached  , we both got a refusal letter for the same exact reasons , he never been to canada before unlike me .

Comment: You cannot just change your situation overnight. In my opinion you will need to give it some time, at least a year. You can’t just change your duration of stay, it will looks like you are just saying anything to please them. Your family ties are not going to change, your family claiming asylum seriously undermines you. I see another refusal if you apply anytime soon.

Comment: My father consulted his attorney and said my best chance is through an express entrey , so the fact I didn't claim refugee even though i came to canada and leave after they were protected doesn't benefit me ??  And should i forget about visa applications and choose immigration road? Thanks for your reply

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Do you want to visit your family, or immigrate to Canada? If you intend to immigrate, then trying to obtain a temporary visitor visa is not a good idea.

Comment: Have your family been accepted to Canada based on their refugee claim, or are they still going through the hearing process?

Comment: No i intend to visit but it seems there is no hope in accepting me any time soon , which make me think in other ways to go there

Comment: Yes they are accepted and waiting for their PR

Comment: @Saro, if your father has a advanced-stage cancer, it might be worth checking if Canada has some emergency type of visa. I had a friend in exactly the same situation who obtained an emergency visitor visa to the US, although he would have trouble otherwise (overstay in the past, entire family in the US, insufficient ties to his current country of residence).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot just change your situation overnight. In my opinion you will need to give it some time, at least a year.

You can’t just change your duration of stay, it will looks like you are just saying anything to please them.

Your family ties are not going to change, **your family claiming asylum seriously undermines you**. I see another refusal if you apply anytime soon. They are reasonable in concluding you will also seek asylum to be with them. If you will reapply do not apply with your husband, you need him to be back home to show strong ties to your home country. It will help if you have children at home.

Regarding the duration of stay I see nothing wrong with it. One month vacation is very normal. I just believe they threw that in there just because they already discredit you due to the family asylum issue.

> Can the location of the VAC affect the decision?

Yes, but it’s likely not statistically significant. Same way approval can depend on which particular visa officer reviewed the case. Some are more accommodating than others but overall not much different (at least in theory).

**Conclusion**

Don’t reapply immediately. Even when you wait for some time and reapply, use an immigration attorney.